# The fastest way to check number in txt file

Tags: c#

H iguys. I have a loop which parse users id's and adds tham to txt file.
What's the best way than to check if this txt has this id skip it ( while next parsing ).
The size of txt rises from 5-..... mb

I tried to add ids to List, but when the size of file if bigger than 5mb the app begins hanging

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: More specifics are required. Is the file read from much more regularly than it's written to? It might be beneficial to sort the IDs as you write them to the file and apply some indexing for fast lookups.

Comment: I tried to add ids to List, but when the size of file if bigger than 5mb the app begins hanging

Comment: @JohnKraft There's nothing wrong with homework questions, per se; as long as they are good questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber you are correct. But if that is the case, it should be tagged as such. I personally don't answer "how to do" homework questions. That's the whole point of homework. Theory questions are different.

Comment: @JohnKraft See the tag Wiki for the [tag:homework] tag: It should no longer be used.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HashSet<int>` or `HashSet<string>`, collect the ids in it, then at the end write the result to the text file.

PS: *Note that HashSet is O(1) while List is O(n)*

Comment: Yes. This.  Hashset<T> is very underused.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably load all of the IDs in the text file into some collection and check if that collection contains the IDs.

I honestly don't think that there's a much more efficient way of doing it than that.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb I believe is to trade time with space. If you want to make copying faster and avoid looking into the file again and again then you may maintain an array or linked list or hash table which also have the id stored in it

Comment: Storing an array would be no better than the `List` he's currently using, and using a `LinkedList` would be much, much worse.

Comment: I thought he is traversing the whole text file to check the id, so using any collection would be better. I am aware that the access time or the O(_n_) differs from collection to collection.

Comment: The question indicates that he's searching the file repeatedly, not just once, so it would be very beneficial to store the values in an appropriate collection in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userIsAlreadyThere = File.ReadLines(path).Contains(userid);
```